# FxCop execution failed with return code '521'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sonarqube, fxcop

I have a one `WEB API` project with some other projects in same solution.

I am getting error `Could not load *.dll`. When `WEB API` project is loading.

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Did you use the FxCop-Gui or via command-line?

Comment: @Micha:I have tried with both.

Answer (score 1):

according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429400(v=vs.80).aspx
The error means 521 = 0x1 + 0x8 + 0x200 , i.e.
- Analysis error
- Assembly load error
- Assembly references error

You could try to set the 'Copy Local' property to true on all references

When you use sonar then you could try adding something like te following line to your sonar-properties.properties

sonar.fxcop.assemblyDependencyDirectories=YourWebsiteFolder/bin/Debug,YourExternaldllFolder